# What is the difference between clEnqueueBarrier and clFinish?

Tags: opencl, gpu

OpenCL 1.1 specification says:

cl_int clEnqueueBarrier(cl_command_queue command_queue)

> clEnqueueBarrier is a synchronization point that ensures that all queued commands in command_queue have finished execution before the next batch of commands can begin execution.

cl_int clFinish(cl_command_queue command_queue)

> Blocks until all previously queued OpenCL commands in command_queue are issued to the associated device and have completed. clFinish does not return until all queued commands in command_queue have been processed and completed. clFinish is also a synchronization point.

Should have to do something with the in-order or out-of-order execution, but I can't see the difference. Are they ever needed if I have in-order execution? At the moment I do something like:

```
...
for(...){
    clEnqueuNDRangeKernel(...);
    clFlush(command_queue);
    clFinish(command_queue);
}
...
```

on an Nvidia GPU. Any relevant comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enqueue a barrier if you are writing an out-of-order queue as one method of ensure dependency.  You could also use the `cl_event` objects to ensure correct ordering of commands on the command queue.

If you are writing your code such that you call a `clFinish` after every kernel invocation, then using `clEnqueueBarrier` will not have any impact on your code, since you are already ensuring ordering.

The point of using the `clEnqueueBarrier` would be a case such as:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1);
clEnqueueBarrier(queue);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2);
```

In this case, kernel2 depends on the results of kernel1. If this queue is out-of-order, then without the barrier kernel2 *could* execute before kernel1, causing incorrect behavior.  You could achieve the same ordering with:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1);
clFinish(queue);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2);
```

because `clFinish` will wait until the queue is empty (all kernels/data transfers have finished).  However, `clFinish` will wait until kernel1 finishes, in this case, while `clEnqueueBarrier` should immediately return control back to the application (allowing you to enqueue more kernels or perform other useful work.

As a side note, I think that `clFinish` will implicitly call `clFlush` so you should not need to call it every time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So summing it up: both do the same, but the clEnqueueBarrier() is an asynchronous function, so it continues the to host code imediately. I tested the two solutions if one has more time requirement then the other, but there seemed to be no such an issue.

Comment: I wonder if clEnqueueBarrier is in fact equivalent to clEnqueueMarker followed by clEnqueueWaitForEvents? Or is there some minute detail that I've overlooked?

Comment: @TomiAarnio It's possible that this can be an implementation of clEnqueueBarrier, but I'm unsure how about clEnqueueMarker works in an out-of-order queue which might affect the semantics of the two.  For in-order queues, I would say this is likely the case.